# New Zealand visa longer stay?

Tags: visas, new-zealand

In the USA if enter with an ESTA you can stay 90 days but if you have a B1/B2 visa, you can stay 180 days (and have the possibility of extending even that with a I-539 form).

I am a citizen of an EU country and as such I am able to enter New Zealand without a visa. However, I am unable to find how could I stay longer than 90 days -- based on the USA example I was thinking maybe if I got a visa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ways to stay longer than 90 days in New Zealand, even as a visitor. For example:

- If you are under 30 (and meet some other conditions) then you may be eligible for a [Working Holiday Scheme](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/work/workingholiday/) visa which lets you stay for a year
- If you apply for a [Visitor Visa](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/visit/) you may request a duration of stay longer than 90 days

If you intend to work in New Zealand, such as if you have a job offer, you can apply for various temporary work visas. You may even apply for such a visa after you have arrived in the country as a tourist.

The [Immigration New Zealand](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/) web site is well laid out and presents the various visa options clearly (see "Find a visa").

Comment: I plan to (in a few years) buy an apartment somewhere (so far Israel and New Zealand are candidates) and winter out there. That's why I am asking; I have seen the website the "you may request a duration of stay longer than 90 days" was unclear and I still don't see that anywhere on the site.

Comment: The visa application form has a space where you enter your intended dates of arrival and departure. I suppose you can request more than 90 days which they may approve.